# ラズパイ+GPSモジュールでGoogle Mapに現在地を表示したいのですが、やり方が分からず困っています。

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi, gps

ラズパイ+GPSモジュールを使ってターミナルから現在の緯度経度を取得することはできているのですが、現在地をGoogle Mapなどで表示（あなたの現在地はここです、というようなものです）が出来なくて困っています。

使用環境

・Raspberry Pi 3
・GPSCAP[（リンクはこちら）](http://einstlab.web.fc2.com/RaspberryPi/GPSCAP.html)

GPSCAPはラズパイマガジン2017年4月号との連動企画で販売されているGPSモジュールで、紙面の指示に従って、下記のようにターミナルから入力することで、ターミナル上に緯度経度を毎秒ごとに表示するところまでは出来ています。

```
    $cd ~/GPSCAP
    $./tude.py
```

すると、下記画像のように緯度経度が表示されます。

[image: 緯度経度がターミナル上に表示された]

※緯度経度の情報は一部伏せてあります

また、付属の別のPythonのプログラムを使うことで、.txt形式で時刻/緯度経度/高度/速度etc...の情報を保存することもできました。

何度もGoogleで検索してみましたが、いわゆる"GPSロガー"（通って来たルートを後からGoogle Map等で読み込んで表示させる）ものはあっても、リアルタイムでGPSモジュールの現在位置をGoogle Mapで表示するものはありませんでした。

（[1つだけTrackrr.ioを使うやり方が書いてあるウェブサイトがありました](https://qiita.com/YusukeHasegawa/items/01cb967ab58a02c0978c)が、Trackrr.ioに新規登録しようとしたところ、何度やっても登録失敗になってしまったので諦めました）

プログラム「超」初心者なので、どのようなスクリプトをどう書けばいいのかというところまで、丁寧にご教授頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/111959

Comment: raspberry pi上でWebサーバを動かしそこにブラウザでアクセスするとGoogle Map上に位置が表示される、とそういうことでしょうか。やりたいことをもう少し具体的にかけませんか。(コメントで返信せず質問を編集して追記なり書き換えなりしてください）

Answer (score -1):

マーカー（位置は、緯度・経度で指定）がついたGoogleマップを表示する方法はGoogle Mapの以下のページで解説されています。
[マーカーが配置された Google マップをウェブサイトに追加する](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)

質問に書かれている”リアルタイムで”が、何を求めていらっしゃるのか判りませんが、定期的に（緯度・経度に変化があったら）Googleマップを書き換えれば現在位置の表示ができると思います。